# PHP: Check if array key has value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array(`$post_options`), it can appear in various guises, the key is dynamic:

It might be like this:

> array(1) { [95]=> string(2) "25" }

It might be like this, the key can be anything:

> array(1) { [05]=> string(2) "" }

I want to add a control statement that controls upon whether or not the value in the first key element has a value.

I have this code:

```
if (!isset($post_options[0])) {
            // value is empty
            var_dump($post_options);
        }
        else {
            // value has value
            echo 'Option Selected';
        }
```

But this is not working, it returns true when the value is set and not set. What is the solution here? Thanks

So if the array appears like this (the value of the first key is empty):

> array(1) { [05]=> string(2) "" }

I want to `var_dump();` in this case

Comment: can you explain more ? what you want exactly and currently what you getting ?

Comment: i think try !empty() or empty() condition

Comment: @jilesh I tried that but no joy, the statement returns true in this case wheter value has value or not.

Comment: you mean value is empty or not empty in both case right ?

Comment: What do you mean by "has a value"? Do you mean that the key must exist in the array? Do you mean that the value must not be `null`? Must the value not be the empty string? How about any other "empty" value? There's so many options here. What *precisely* do you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't know the first key of array - use `array_keys`, for example, to get all keys of your array.

```
$ar = array('95' => 'val');
$keys = array_keys($ar);
$first_item = $ar[$keys[0]]; 
var_dump($first_item);    // outputs: string(3) "val"
```

Another option can be a `current` function, which will return you current element of an array. Considering that you don't move array pointer, code can be:

```
$ar = array('95' => 'new_val', '02' => 'val2');
$cur = current($ar);
var_dump($cur);  // outputs: string(7) "new_val"
```

After that you can use standard `empty`function to check:

```
if (empty($cur))
```

or

```
if (empty($first_item))
```

Answer (score 37):

Depending on your exact requirements, there are three alternatives.

1. [`array_key_exists($key, $array)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)
   This is the simplest option. It returns `true` if the array has the given key, and otherwise returns `false`.
2. [`isset($array[$key])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
   Slightly more strict than `array_key_exists` since it also requires that the value assigned to the key is not `null`.
3. [`!empty($array[$key])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (note the `!`) This is the strictest option, as it requires the value to not be any empty value (i.e., not `null`, `false`, `0`, `'0'`, etc).

There's some other options, again, depending on exact requirements. It looks to me that you are looking for the `!empty` option, since it will (in particular) reject empty strings.

Comment: As a note, assume `$var = ''` using `isset($var)` wil return `TRUE`, to test for and empty string make sure to use `empty()` - ref: [php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (!isset($post_options[0])) {            // value is empty
    if(!empty($post_options[0])) {
          var_dump($post_options);          
    }           
}
```

Comment: empty checks for value and isset checks for array present or not (If you have keys without values then it returns true only. )
To check the value in array we need to use empty

Answer (score 0):

isset checks whether the array position exists or not, not whether it cointains or it doesn't contain a value.

You better have a look at the [empty](http://php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php) function to do this

```
if (empty($post_options[0])) {
    // value is empty
    var_dump($post_options);
} else {
    // value has value
    echo 'Option Selected';
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: `isset` actually checks whether the keys exists *and* does not map to `null`.

Comment: This returns false whether a value is set or not.

Comment: then I'm afraid your array element is not empty otherwise the function would work. Try to print the elements in both cases and see the values.